How aistudio can use directly file from Google Drive with code
When I select a large file from google drive on Googles AI Studio. Googles AI Studio loads my file very fast. However when I use code (Nodejs), I need to download this file from then upload this file to Gemini (this file is large so I get "fetch failed" error).
So have any method to use directly file from google drive (use file ID, ...)?

No there is no way to have Gemini API access files stored on your drive account.  However you can upload them to the Files api and then pass that to Gemini api and it will then be able to access it.  This works well if you need to access the same file more then once.
// Make sure to include these imports:
// import { GoogleAIFileManager } from "@google/generative-ai/server";
// import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";
const fileManager = new GoogleAIFileManager(process.env.API_KEY);

const uploadResult = await fileManager.uploadFile(
  `${mediaPath}/jetpack.jpg`,
  {
    mimeType: "image/jpeg",
    displayName: "Jetpack drawing",
  },
);
// View the response.
console.log(
  `Uploaded file ${uploadResult.file.displayName} as: ${uploadResult.file.uri}`,
);

const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.API_KEY);
const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash" });
const result = await model.generateContent([
  "Tell me about this image.",
  {
    fileData: {
      fileUri: uploadResult.file.uri,
      mimeType: uploadResult.file.mimeType,
    },
  },
]);
console.log(result.response.text());

